# How can i change app data location?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, insufficient-memory, app2sd

My default write disk is external sd card , my internal sd total space is 5.28 gb available is 4.66 gb my sdcard total space is 14.83 am using 16 gb available in sd card is 11 gb . my phone storage RAM is 1 gb (0.89) available is 65 mb .but when ever i downlaod any apps from play store its showing insufficent memmory like that. that time i goto settings > storage > phone storage > apps then i clear data of some apps i mainly used. my default write didk is external sd 11 + gb free . then i download apptosd app from playstore after also i am facing same issue . is there any option to change our app data phone storage to internal sd or external sd please. (my os is Android 4.4.2 kit kat ) ("Remember I can move app to sd card and internal sd ") by using of cm clean master app ) i cannot move app data to sd card or internal)

Answer (score 1):

Application data is secure data stored on a partition with many restrictions.  Android does not allow you to move your data somewhere, where no such security for your data exists. If it would, malicious apps could easily steal user credentials, debit card info, etc. Therefore, Android does not allow you to move your applications' data.

Comment: But in my friend phone videocon quad z51 is kitkat 4.4.2 he don't have that issue all data is going to external sd or internal he dont have p phone storage option .when we go to settings > storage there we can seee internal sd and external sd only

Answer (score 1):

On your device:

1. Go to your phone settings → Developer Tools.

   If you don't see the developer tools options, go to Settings → About phone and tap on the build number seven times and then you should get the developer tools on your settings menu.
2. Turn on USB Debugging from Developer tools.

On your computer:

1. Make sure that you have the latest device drivers (I'm assuming you're using Windows OS. This isn't necessary for Linux or iOS).
2. Download the adb (Android Device Bridge) tool. It usually comes with the Android SDK, but you can find it [here](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/).
3. Connect your device to the computer using a USB cable.
4. Run adb from Command prompt using one of these commands:

   ```
   adb shell pm set-install-location 0
   adb shell pm set-install-location 2  # alternative command
   ```

   The first command sets your install location for phone memory. The other one sets to external SD Card.

Answer (score 1):

ok you can do it efficient, if you have root permission..

now i assume you know what is rooting.. if not, please don't follow this answer..

there are two ways available, easy but hard way and hard but easy way..

1) easy but hard way, install xposed and download a module name called "XInternalSD", enable it and restart your phone.. now go to that app and check "enable for all user apps" option.. and thats all.. its done.. from now on you can install any app or game, and it will directly installed to your sd card.. no more "insufficent space" warning..
now why this method called Easy but the Hard way?
its simple, xposed is a system level hook.. so if you dont know what you are doing, it will brick your device..

2) using link2sd app.. download it from playstore.. and go to options and set "install location" to external.. thats all.. but this method doesnt force all apps to sd.. if an app requires to be installed in internal, it will leave as it is.. optionally you can format your sd card to make an ext partition for installing all apps on sd card.. thats all..

note: these two methods needs root permission..

Answer (score 0):

In the samsung J1 ace goto settings/storage/sdcard/three dotmenu to set it